# Simulating Excel's vlookup with CTEs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

One can simulate the vlookup function from Excel by using:

```
select b.col, (case when a.val is NULL then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end)
from b left outer join
     (select distinct a.val
      from a
     ) a
     on b.col = a.val;
```

Then multiple CTEs can be nested like this:

```
WITH    cte1 AS
        (
        SELECT  1 AS id
        ),
        cte2 AS
        (
        SELECT  2 AS id
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    cte2
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    cte1
```

**Question is**: How would one perform a vlookup from the first example by using `ct1.col` and `ct2.col` instead of `a.col and b.col`? I'm trying to perform a vlookup between two query outputs without storing them into temp tables or tables.

I am thinking of something like this:

```
; with cte1 as ( select pd.value as value from pentd pd
inner join aster a on a.aid = pd.aid
where pid = 10
and a.name = 'ls'),
with cte2 as( select pd.value as value from pentd pd
inner join aster a on a.aid = pd.aid
where pid = 15
and a.name = 'ls' )

select (select value from cte2),
(case 
when cte1.value is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end)
from cte2
left outer join
(select distinct value from cte1) cte1
on cte1.value = cte2.value
```

But this returns to me (of course the code above is just an example, can't link the real data or output)

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Any idea if what I am trying to achieve is possible and if yes, then how can I use it for multiple values while avoiding the error?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 but I'm also interested in SQL Server 2008 solutions.

**cte1**  - Columns used here with the join, since I only select value

```
aid     name     value
10       ls      123.123
10       ls      422.433
10       ls      56.32
```

**cte2** - Columns used here with the join, since I only select value

```
aid     name     value
15      ls       123.123
15      ls       34.21
15      ls       21.256
```

**expected output**

```
value
123.123
```

Comment: Perhaps some sample data with expected output would make this a bit easier to understand and provide you with a useful answer. It's hard to follow what you're trying to do with names like "cte1" and "pentd" and multiple subqueries in places where subqueries shouldn't exist.

Comment: well, can't really provide my data. But I can describe the idea: You have a table from which you select a column and join this table with another, filter the results by an id and a string. That's your first `cte`, the second is the same but using another `id`. Then use the results in the cte's to find the duplicates among the two values. You don't have to use my columns, I would like an example. Just follow the logic: both cte's have an inner join and have a where clause which filters by  number and a string. You can use any naming convention you want. It will be of great help and I can adapt

Comment: You don't need to provide your actual data, but it would help if you could provide *example* data and expected output.  SO has a handy guide to building [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please see my edit. ps: I wanted to avoid providing some data sample because it happened that sometimes people provide an answer which solves the problem but in another way than the guidelines of the question. I would like to use CTEs and the simulation of vlookup function. If that's not possible, other solutions are also more than welcomed! thank you for your time

Comment: regarding the downvotes. What should I do to improve the quality of the question? there are tons of questions on SO which show no effort, originality and have tons of up votes. I thought this project might be really interesting for me and others and feels like it's harder and harder nowadays to ask a good sql question.

Comment: @CM2K There was only one downvote; don't stress out about it. It probably happened because your original revision (before any edits) had no sample data or expected results, so it was hard to understand what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select (select value from cte2),
```

This line is your problem. The nested query (the bit in parentheses) returns multiple values. You can't select tables (meaning multiple rows) as single columns. Try this instead:

```
select cte2.value,
(case 
when cte1.value is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end)
from cte2
left outer join
(select distinct value from cte1) cte1
on cte1.value = cte2.value
```

You can change it to `select distinct cte2.value` if you need to filter out duplicates, or migrate the `distinct` options up to your CTEs.

Comment: will try it out tomorrow when i'll have access to the testing environment. +1 for pointing out the error of my ways. Thanks

Comment: tested, works. now the question is: Do you really need sample data for this? It's quite a clear mistake which I couldn't see, but someone with sql experience, like you, can spot this quickly.

Comment: The location of the mistake was obvious without sample data, but what it should be changed to (meaning what are your desired results) was not, because I'm not good at Excel. A quality answer usually needs that information to be complete, otherwise it's just a helpful comment. It's also just a good habit to have, because sometimes explaining everything clearly can help you figure it out yourself. That's called [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).